# Looping through array_values to get records

Tags: php

```
 public function Read($Table, $Fields, $Where, $OrderBy, $Limit) {
        if ($this->TableExists($Table)) {
            $Query = "SELECT " . $Fields . " FROM " . "$Table";
            if ($Where != "") {
                $Query .= " WHERE " . $Where;
            }
            if ($OrderBy != "") {
                $Query .= " ORDER BY" . $OrderBy;
            }
            if ($Limit != "") {
                $Query .= " LIMIT " . $Limit;
            }
            $Result = mysql_query($Query);
            $Records = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
            //Extracting the field names
            $Keys = array_keys($Records);
            $this->Keys = $Keys;
            //Extracting recordset
            while($Values = array_values($Records)){

            $this->Values = $Values;
            }
            return $this->Values;
            return $this->Keys;
        }
        else {
            echo "This table doesn't exists!";
        }
        } // End Read();
?>

        <table>
            <tr>

                <?php
                foreach ($Object->Keys as $Key) {
                    ?>
                    <th><?php echo $Key; ?></th>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
          // Here i want the database record to be displayed.
        </table>
```

Actually i m trying to make a generic class to fetch results. The goal is to let the php code free from html elements. I've successfully done with displaying array_keys.
I m making some mistake in looping i think for displaying array_values  I want the record to be dislplayed in table Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Why bother splitting the results into two separate key and value arrays? Also, the MySQL extension is deprecated, etc, etc

Comment: Phil this is just for learning purpose. Yes i know about mysql but i am scared of jumping into mysqli or pdo since i m beginner

Comment: Why would any particular library matter to a beginner? Pretend the MySQL extension doesn't exist, read the documentation for MySQLi and PDO and use what you feel comfortable with.

Comment: which is more better b/w them ?

Comment: That's subjective. Please take the time to **read the documentation for MySQLi and PDO and use what you feel comfortable with**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding $this->Values each iteration of the loop, try:

```
$this->Values = array();
while($Records && $Values = array_values($Records)){
    $this->Values[] = $Values;
    $Records = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
}
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` pulls an associative array from the result set each time it's called until there are no rows left, so the idea of iterating `while($Records && ...` means it'll keep looping, fetching rows and putting them in to `$this->Values` until `$Results` is false.

and:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($Object->Keys as $Key) { ?>
            <th><?php echo $Key; ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($Object->Values as $Values) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($Values as $Value) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $Value; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Here is just an extension of what you were doing, except because `$this->Values` is an array, you need to iterate it, then the arrays inside each value. It's a [2D array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp).

There are better ways to achieve your goal, but this should function.  Consider looking in to `mysqli` or the `PDO` too.

Comment: Damn too good ! Calcinai but it went above my head :s can you please guide me a lil bit how it is working !

Comment: I've explained it a bit more.